# SQL select the row with max value using row_number() or rank()

Tags: sql-server

I have data of following kind:

```
RowId   Name    Value
1       s1      12
22      s1      3
13      s1      4
10      s2      14
22      s2      5
3       s2      100
```

I want to have the following output:

```
RowId   Name    Value
1       s1      12
3       s2      100
```

I am currently using temp tables to get this in two step. I have been trying to use row_number() and rank() functions but have not been successful.

Can someone please help me with syntax as I feel row_number() and rank() will make it cleaner?

Edit:
I changed the rowId to make it a general case

Edit:
I am open to ideas better than row_number() and rank() if there are any.

Comment: What would you want if the `value` for `RowId` 22, `Name` s1 was also `12`? Or is that not an issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `rank()` you can get multiple results when a name has more than 1 row with the same max value. If that is what you are wanting, then switch `row_number()` to `rank()` in the following examples.

For the highest `value` per `name` (top 1 per group), using [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
select sub.RowId, sub.Name, sub.Value
from (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
        partition by Name 
        order by Value desc
      )
  from t
  ) as sub
where sub.rn = 1
```

---

I can not say that there are any 'better' alternatives, but there are alternatives. Performance may vary.

**`cross` [`apply`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)** version:

```
select distinct
    x.RowId
  , t.Name
  , x.Value
from t
  cross apply (
    select top 1
          *
      from t as i
      where i.Name = t.Name
      order by i.Value desc
    ) as x;
```

---

**[`top with ties`](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option)** using [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) version:

```
select top 1 with ties
    *
  from t
  order by 
    row_number() over (
      partition by Name
      order by Value desc
      )
```

---

This `inner join` version has the same issue as using `rank()` instead of `row_number()` in that you can get multiple results for the same name if a name has more than one row with the same max value.

`inner join` version:

```
select t.*
from t
  inner join (
    select MaxValue = max(value), Name
    from t
    group by Name
    ) as m
      on t.Name  = m.Name
     and t.Value = m.MaxValue;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to use `ROW_NUMBER()` you can do it this way:

```
With Cte As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By Name Order By Value Desc) RN
    From    YourTable
)
Select  RowId, Name, Value
From    Cte
Where   RN = 1;
```

Comment: You got it, I thought OP wanted `RowId` to be from `row_number()` until OP updated the question.

Comment: @SqlZim OP had changed question

Comment: I was missing partition by. Sorry about editing the question.

Comment: @Zanam no need to be sorry, clarifying the question is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something... Why use row_number() or rank?

```
select rowid, name, max(value) as value
from table
group by rowid, name
```

Comment: grouping by `rowid` and `name` is going to give you all rows though, right?

Comment: group by here will produce same table as original as for each rowID and name, I have only 1 value

Comment: ah got it. I see. @SqlZim Thanks